# How I can find action from URl

Tags: magento-1.9

How I can find action from URl, if I have just  http://mysite.loc/onestepcheckout/
I now, how find it, if I have a something like that:

```
agentdeposit/adminhtml_order/finalize/order_id/
    |            |              |
    | Module     |              |
                 | Controller   |
                                | Action
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default url structure is like you say

> /{module}/{controller}/{action}

but there are some special cases when you don't have 3 parameters. You can have 2....

> /{module}/{controller}/

This is equivalent to

> /{module}/{controller}/index

...or you can have only 1...

> /{module}/

this is equivalent to

> /{module}/index/index

So when something is missing, it defaults to `index`.

Comment: TY, understood.